# Dynamic Select Throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React component that involves the use of a select HTML input.  I've defined it as follows:

```
 <select className="form-control-mt-3" id="clientList" name="clientList" 
 onChange={this.handleClientChange} value={this.state.clientId || ''}>
      <option key={-1} value={-1}>Select a Client</option>
      {this.state.clients.map(o => {
           return <option key={o.clientId} value={o.clientId}>(o.clientName)
      </option>
      })}
      </select>
```

When I run this page, I receive a TypeError that references the line `this.state.clients.map`.

I thought that the following code block would assign the array of clients suh that the select would render properly:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        modalIsOpen: false,
        clients: [],
        clientId: -1,
        clientAccounts: [],
        coldWallets: [],
        hotWallets: [],
        coins: []
    }
    this.handleClientChange = this.handleClientChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAccountChange = this.handleAccountChange.bind(this);
    this.handleColdWalletChange = this.handleColdWalletChange.bind(this);
    this.handleHotWalletChange = this.handleHotWalletChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCoinTypeChange = this.handleCoinTypeChange.bind(this);
}

handleClientChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const clientId = value;

    this.setState({
        clientId: clientId
    });
}

handleAccountChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const clientAccountId = value;

    this.setState({
       clientAccountId: clientAccountId
    });
}

handleColdWalletChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const coldWalletId = value;

    this.setState({
        coldWalletId: coldWalletId
    });
}

handleHotWalletChange(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const hotWalletId = value;

    this.setState({
        hotWalletId: hotWalletId
    });
}

handleCoinTypeChange(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const coinTypeId = value;

    this.setState({
        coinTypeId: coinTypeId
    });
}

componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: nextProps.modalIsOpen,
        infoMessage: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        clients: nextProps.clients,
        clientAccounts: nextProps.clientAccounts,
        coldWallets: nextProps.coldWallets,
        hotWallets: nextProps.hotWallets,
        coins: nextProps.coins
    }, () => {
        let clientId = this.state.clientId;
        let selectedClientId = { clientId: -1, active: false};
        if(clientId !== -1) {
            clientId = parseInt(clientId, 10);
            clientService.getClient(this.state.clientId)
                .then((response) => {
                    selectedClientId = response.data;
                    this.setState({
                        infoMessage: '', errorMessage: '',
                        clientId: clientId,
                        client: Object.assign({}, selectedClientId)
                    });
                })
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                infoMessage: '', errorMessage: '',
                clientId: clientId,
                client: Object.assign({}, selectedClientId)
            });
        }
        });
}
```

How do I ensure that my client names are available in the Select HTML input given that I'm calling into a ClientService to obtain said values?

Comment: You can check if `this.state.clients` is defined and then `.map` like : `if(this.state.clients){ {this.state.clients.map.()} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this validation

```
<select className="form-control-mt-3" id="clientList" name="clientList" 
 onChange={this.handleClientChange} value={this.state.clientId || ''}>
      <option key={-1} value={-1}>Select a Client</option>
      {this.state.clients ? this.state.clients.map(o => {
           return <option key={o.clientId} value={o.clientId}>(o.clientName)
      </option>
      }) : <option>No values</option> } 
      </select>
```

Comment: Another alternative is use  Array.isArray method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: This works.  Turns out I need to call into the CientService to retrieve data from the server side API.